# Using different cloud hosts for app and db/will there be latency with Mongo Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, cloud, web-applications

Is it ok to host both a web app and db server on different cloud providers? Traditionally you really needed to host both on the same network - but I'm wondering if, with modern networks, this is less of a necessity.

I have a web app (Aurelia/ASP.Net Core) hosted on Linode and I need to add a mongo db server. I really don't want to have to manage the db servers - so would prefer to use a cloud service/PAAS like MongoAtlas or mLab etc but my concern is latency. I'm hoping that I could use either of these if I chose a data center in the same country/location as my Linodes are hosted.

My app should be ok with not-so-real-time responses - but lags of a few seconds won't work.

Can anyone comment on experiences with this?

Answer (score 4):

I can tell you my own experience.

I have a web server hosted in Azure which store into and retrieve data from a M10 MongoDB Atlas instance hosted in AWS. Both instantes are located in Europe datacenters.
Communication latency between these two instances is about **12 milliseconds** per query, no matter what type of query is it. For example, if I want to retrieve some data that MongoDB can found in 2ms, it needs about 12ms + 2ms to finish the query.
This is a big issue in my case, because sometimes I want to proceed with multiple queries, one after another, and those extra 12ms are killing the performance of my application.